# Angular binding, despite importing required module, 'Can't Bind to -------' error, 'serve and compile ' works fine

Tags: javascript, html, angular, visual-studio-code, ide

My Angular application was working fine, but all binding stopped working although I have imported the necessary modules like `FormsModule` for `ngModel` etc. Removed `node_module` and `npm install` but nothing is working. Uninstalled all VC plugins but issue is still there.

> `ng serve` works fine

In each module I have imports which were working till today morning
[image]

[image]

```
import { DealsRoutingModule } from './deals-routing.module';
import { DealsListComponent } from './list/deals-list.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { DropzoneModule } from 'ngx-dropzone-wrapper';
import { NgxPaginationModule } from 'ngx-pagination';
import { PipesModule } from '../pipes/pipes.module';
import { CalendarModule } from 'primeng/calendar';
import { MDBBootstrapModulesPro } from 'ng-uikit-pro-standard';
import { AddDealComponent } from './add/add-deal.component';
import { ShareModule } from '../components/share.module';
import { ViewDealsComponent } from './view/view-deals.component';
import { LogsComponent } from './logs/logs.component';
import { AutocompleteLibModule } from 'angular-ng-autocomplete';
import { ReciprocalDealClientPipe } from '../pipes/reciprocal-deal-client.pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [DealsListComponent, AddDealComponent, ViewDealsComponent, LogsComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    DealsRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    DropzoneModule,
    NgxPaginationModule,
    PipesModule,
    ShareModule,
    CalendarModule,
    AutocompleteLibModule,
    MDBBootstrapModulesPro.forRoot()
  ],
  exports:[
    ViewDealsComponent
  ],
  providers:[ReciprocalDealClientPipe]
})
export class DealsModule { }
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Does this happen to anyone?

I am using Angular

> 6

and

Mdb (ng-uikit-pro-standard):

> 7.5.1

**NOTE:** Serve and build commands are working fine, just red lines in VS Code is frustrating.

Anyone please?